# vba grouping of logical operators

Tags: vba, excel

Basically i want then Negated Or (NOR)

in vba i want to achieve the following logical grouping in an if statement:

```html
x1 or x2 or x3 or <SPAN STYLE="text-decoration:overline">x4 or x5</SPAN>
```

The first 3 conditions are just connected with or. The last 2 conditions shall first be evaluated with or and then negated.

So far i tried:

```
x1 or x2 or x3 or not (x4 or x5)
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

EXAMPLE:

```
IF textbox1 = "" or textbox2 = "" or textbox3 = "" or not (option1 = false
or option2 = false)
```

Basically i want then Negated Or (NOR)

```
0 0 -> 1
0 1 -> 0
1 0 -> 0
1 1 -> 0
```

Comment: i tried to clarify my question.

Comment: And doesn't seem to work is not sufficiently descriptive. Describe what is happening so we can help.

Comment: I second @QHarr, having some example use case/data would be extremely helpfull here.

Comment: Also if x3 = true, then by default not(x4 or x5) is true

Comment: its just to show the logic, as i found no other overline option

Comment: overline means negating the complete or statement, means <code>not()</code>

Comment: Thanks for adding an example

Comment: i edited the example. The parethesis shall only evaluate true, if x4 and x5 are 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not actually an answer but hopefully a helping code to make you go further:

```
Sub Logicals()
    Dim x1 As Boolean, x2 As Boolean, x3 As Boolean, x4 As Boolean, x5 As Boolean

    If x1 Or x2 Or x3 Or Not (x4 Or x5) Then MsgBox "Got it" ' prompts the message "Got it", since x1, x2, and x3 are False by default and Not (x4 Or x5) = True (being both x4 and x5 False)


    x4 = True ' the same with x5 = True
    If x1 Or x2 Or x3 Or Not (x4 Or x5) Then MsgBox "Got it" ' doesn't prompt the message "Got it" since x1, x2, and x3 are False by default and Not (x4 Or x5) = False (being x4 True)

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused - he already tried `x1 or x2 or x3 or not (x4 or x5)` in his question but I guess it was just the explanation of why he was after.

Comment: Well, i failed to make the right conditions. i did "not(x4=0 or x5=0)" when i wanted "not(x4 or x5)". Thanks, your post made that clear to me.@jamheadart: I oversaw the "=0" in my code that changed the evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

Are x4 and x5 are supposed to be a combined logic? So the outcome of this comparison should be the bool value of the larger logic, with x1, x2 and x3?

Do you perhaps intend to mean:

```
x1 or x2 or x3 or (x4 and x5)
```

This way: if either x4 or x5 is false, it will return as a false.

Comment: I clarified my question further. The parethesis shall only evaluate true, if x4 and x5 are 0. The AND doesn't accomplish this.